# Lotus Notes 8.5 Hide 'Sent By' Field

Tags: email, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

We have Lotus Notes 8.5 in our organisation. We have a group mailbox that we would like to hide the 'Sent By' field for emails sent out.

Can anyone please advise how this can be setup? I can't find much help on The Google...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Team Mailbox template on OpenNTF which provides the functionality to be able to respond with a team/group email address instead of your own email address: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=8E156950C4FB032686257760006044D1